# Java - How to filter items from a list so that only one per element attribute is present?

Tags: java, java-8

Say I have a  `List<Bottle>`, where a `Bottle` is defined as such:

```
public class Bottle {
    String id;
    String color;
}
```

Suppose I put the following into the list:

- ID: "1", color: "blue"
- ID: "2", color: "green"
- ID: "3", color: "red"
- ID: "4", color: "green"
- ID: "5", color: "red"
- ID: "6", color: "purple"

Is there a quick way to get a new `List<Bottle>` containing just IDs 1,2,3,6 , i.e. unique on the "color" attribute?

Please note that I'd like to skip the part where I create a side `List<String>` containing already set colors.

Comment: *unique on the "color" attribute?* - based on what? Why should ID 3 be preferred over ID 5?

Comment: @slim well... Actually it is. I mean, the request is the same (a succint way to filter distinct values based on an attribute of them in place of the equals method).

Comment: @BackSlash actually I don't care whether I'll get 3 over 5 or vice versa. I want a single "red" bottle.

Comment: @EdoardoMariaLiotta either my comment was a brainfart, or it was linked to a different question at the time. Anyway, comment removed.